# Using a variable value when defining in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

```
$product_id_string = $_GET['product_id'];
$product_id = (int)$product_id_string;


//this should be derived from GET or the method you use to distinguish entities
define('ENTITY_ID', $product_id);
```

The above code is part of a plugin that I am attempting to modify - If I change $product_id to a number, the code works - however when I try to GET the product_id, a 0 ends up being saved to the database instead of the GET variable.

Example of working code:

```
define('ENTITY_ID', 2547);
```

If I echo the $product_id, I receive the number I want.

```
$product_id_string = $_GET['product_id'];
$product_id = (int)$product_id_string;
echo $product_id; //Returns 2547
define('ENTITY_ID', $product_id); //Ends up saving as 0 in database
```

Comment: Where is the code to store `ENTITY_ID` into your db?

Comment: check this : `$defined = define("ENTITY_ID", "$product_id");` and `var_dump($defined)` since define returns true or false

Comment: show your code, where u are using ENTITY_ID or echo ENTITY_ID; before insertion... check what r u getting in this variable.

Comment: and what is the result of echo ENTITY_ID; ???

Comment: Check how to convert in int value [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd: check this line, he is getting proper vlaue.. echo $product_id; //Returns 2547

Comment: echo ENTITY_ID returns the correct value, this is what is confusing me.

Comment: if _echo ENTITY_ID returns the correct value_, issue with database query. either you can share it OR you can fix it by yourself.

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd ENTITY_ID returns "0" in other files when I use a variable to set the value of ENTITY_ID as seen above. If however I set ENTITY_ID explicitly such as "1234", then the other files referencing ENTITY_ID return 1234. But as soon as I use define(ENTITY_ID, $variable) - the variable seems to make the ENTITY_ID unreadable for other files. What could I do to fix this?

Comment: Hope you use `define('ENTITY_ID', $product_id);` code before every thing. I mean like we create MySql connection.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below statement to convert to int. That will fix the issue

```
$product_id = intval($product_id_string);
```